# CSS Buscar Elemento a JS

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Boas, estou agora a iniciar programação em HTML5 + JavaScript + CSS e estou com uma dúvida que suponho que seja básica, mas que não consigo achar resposta. Eu criei uma canvas em HTML5 e como não estava a conseguir adicionar botões(criados em HTML) na canvas, decidi fazer os meus próprios botões em JavaScript. A minha dúvida é: Eu queria personalizar o botão e como o criei em JS, existe alguma forma do CSS ir buscar o botão a JS em vez de HTML?

Comment: Como assim criou em JS? ousou `appendChild` com string? `createElement`?  CSS sempre observa o HTML, eles estao no html?

Comment: Você pode criar o botão pelo JS e vincular uma classe para ele e passar atributos para a classe normalmente, o importante é tem uma classe ou ID para que se encontre com o CSS

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar todo o design do botão em uma Classe CSS e quando adicionar o botão em JS você adiciona ele com a Classe.

CSS:

```
.btn {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JS:

```
var newNode = document.createElement('button');
newNode.className = 'btn';
newNode.innerHTML = 'Botão 1';
```

Comment: E como inseria esse botão na canvas?

Comment: Como você estava inserindo antes?

Comment: criei uma classe botao, onde desenhava um retangulo e inseria texto por cima, mas desisti dessa ideia por não conseguir personalizar o botão